# How to add X value to Y rows iterated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If the period is X days, I want the slush to be summed over that time period(the time period is not equal to the length of the dataframe for each slush variable).

I want a new column A to show the Slush of that row + the prior slush within an appropriate period, where in this case, period = row.

**I have checked other posts, I don't believe it is Cumsum as the value is not carried over indefinitely and instead is dropped after its period is over.**

Data

| Slush | Period |
| --- | --- |
| 85 | 1 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 40 | 3 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 22 | 4 |

Desired Output:

| Slush | Period | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 1 | 85 |
| 20 | 3 | 20 |
| 40 | 3 | 60 |
| 15 | 1 | 75 |
| 22 | 4 | 62 |

Comment: Hi Mozway, I don't believe cumsum is a fit as I don't want to cumulatively sum it until the end of the dataframe, I only want the A to be cumulative sum of slush for the period of index + period, and then dropped/carried over

Comment: OK, I get it, you're right, it's a nice question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for a custom cumsum:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))

mask = a < (a+df['Period'].to_numpy())[:,None]

df['A'] = (np.triu(mask) * df['Slush'].to_numpy()[:,None]).sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
   Slush  Period   A
0     85       1  85
1     20       3  20
2     40       3  60
3     15       1  75
4     22       4  62
```

Intermediates:

```
np.triu(mask)

array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])

(np.triu(mask) * df['Slush'].to_numpy()[:,None])

array([[85,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 20, 20, 20,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 40, 40, 40],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 22]])
```

Comment: Thats great! thank you! If I were to instead create another column with dates rather than using the rows themselves as periods, how would I adjust this ?

Comment: @Samuel hard to say exactly without a clear example, but you should be able to achieve the same with timedeltas, the critical part is to build the mask of booleans, you can then use any condition you want.